# How to hide fully qualified DNS Host Name of Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We got an issue in penetration testing, that fully qualified Host Name ec2-IpAddress.example.amazonaws.com is being exposed, Can anyone help to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What do you mean by it is exposed e.g. is the security group for the instance has inbound rule allowing connection from any IP?

Comment: We are using the load balancer.During penetration testing, our testing team find  the Ip Address and Host Name like ec2-IpAddress.example.amazonaws.com Is that possible so that we can hide it.For testing they used Qualys

Comment: This needs clarification from the tester. The ec2-x-x-x-x hostname is simply the DNS PTR record to the hostname, so the fact that it exists is not a security issue, any more than any other reverse-DNS entry.  If your server is *answering* incoming HTTP requests with that value in the incoming `Host` header, you should probably fix your server configuration so that it returns an error, but also if your server behind an ELB actually has a public IP, that is a more serious flaw in your design -- the balancer has public IPs, but the server should not.  Exactly what issue is being discussed?

Comment: @Michael Our servers are behind ELB.

Comment: @Narendra do the servers also have their own public IPs instead of being in a private subnet with a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance as the subnet's default route?  And do the instance security groups allow access to port 80 from the Internet?

Comment: @Michael I  check it,and will update you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable DNS host names on your VPC subnet.

> If your VPC is enabled to support DNS hostnames, each instance that
>   receives a public IP address or an Elastic IP address is also given a
>   public DNS hostname. We resolve a public DNS hostname to the public IP
>   address of the instance outside the instance network, and to the
>   private IP address of the instance from within the instance network.
>   For more information, see Using DNS with Your VPC.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ipv4-addresses

Comment: This would only turn it off *inside* the VPC.  I don't think that's going to be the issue.

Comment: Just tested this. When I set `DNS hostnames`
to `No` , no instance is issued the "ec2-xxx-216-134-214.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" type DNS name - even existing instances.  In instance description, Public DNS (IPv4) is null.

Comment: But `dig -x 203.0.113.100` (example IP) still works from the Internet, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it would have to.  But the VPC does not advertise the hostname in this setting, only the IP. A reverse lookup will certainly reveal the name, which the OP is concerned about.

Comment: ...which I suspect means this solution doesn't really address the issue (although admittedly at this point, it's not entirely clear what the exact issue is).