# AWS Lightsail - IPv4 Public DNS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-lightsail

Recently I found out the public IPv4 Public DNS domain from my Worpress in AWS Lightsail instance is public and indexed by Google.

This is becoming a huge problem because is around 4,000 urls already indexed and my main domain is around 20,000 and will start to lose relevancy.

Any ideas how to hide this from public? Redirect from https://ec2-1-234-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ to main domain ou something that's solve this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you want your whole website hidden from Google? If so, see: [Disabling search engine indexing for WordPress](https://www.cloudaccess.net/wordpress-tutorials/163-maintenance/1184-disabling-search-engine-indexing-for-wordpress-2.html) Or do you want it hidden from everybody in the world (as a private website that nobody can access)?

Comment: I want to hidden the https://ec2-1... URL, my main domain I want to keep it. The problem is a duplicity of content in web because for Google i.e. there is two websites with same content but different URLs.

Comment: Ah! So you are happy for Google to index the website via its Domain Name but you want to stop it via the IP address. This seems like it could help: [AWS Wordpress site accessible using both domain and public IP. How to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69312139/174777)

Comment: The Google is indexing the domain https://ec2-1-234-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ not the IP public address as 0.0.0.0, that's the issue. This public IPv4 DNS is my problem.

Comment: The root problem is that you're somehow exposing the EC2 DNS name, perhaps via internal links. But one possible solution is to use a _canonical URL_ to tell search engines the proper URL for a page (it's an element in the page; you'll have to search for the proper syntax).

Comment: After you mention that, by somehow the Jetpack is asking me about use the EC2 DNS as the main domain. But I've double checked in WP config and there is nothing filled with this URL. I will make a full lookup in database by this URL.

Comment: Ah! Same as: [How to hide fully qualified DNS Host Name of Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48145012/174777)

Answer (score 1):

From [DNS attributes for your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames):

> **Public IPv4 DNS**
> A public (external) IPv4 DNS hostname takes the form `ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com` for the us-east-1 Region, and `ec2-public-ipv4-address.region.compute.amazonaws.com` for other Regions. The Amazon DNS server resolves a public DNS hostname to the public IPv4 address of the instance outside the network of the instance, and to the private IPv4 address of the instance from within the network of the instance.

You can **disable DNS hostnames** by going to the VPC and choosing **Actions / Edit VPC settings**, then **disable** the "Enable DNS hostnames" option:

[[image: DNS hostnames]

Comment: Oh, got it. I found the settings, turned off,  but the all the URLs still live. This take any time to shut down?

Comment: I presume that it would depend on the TTL set on the DNS name. Since you aren't using an Elastic IP address, you could Stop the instance and the Start it again. This would allocate a different IP address to the instance, so the old links won't work. It would take a while for Google to realise this and remove the links. If you want to have a static IP address, you could [Create a static IP address and attach it to a Lightsail instance - Amazon Lightsail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lightsail/latest/userguide/lightsail-create-static-ip.html).

Comment: Nah, already turned off the Lightsail instance. Turned on and nothing, still the same. And I have a fixed IP address to the instance, maybe I should attach a new one? I need to have one because I use Cloudflare to manage my DNS.

Comment: Yes, changing IP address will at least invalidate the Google results that point to the 'old' IP address.